Update a migrated git repo taken from TFS
Months ago I've done a big migration of a git repo, now some user made change on TFS even if they were told not to do... is there a way I can update from a specific changeset all the branches in git using git-tfs to get the delta?
Thanks

Here's the general pattern:

You can use the git tfs --changeset=1234 option to start git-tfs from any changeset. This will give you a new Git repo with a small set of commits with a root commit which equals where you left off in the other repo.
Checkout a common branch (perhaps main or similar) in your existing repo, and then Cherry-pick the commits from the new repo.
Update all other desired branches using rebase or merge, the same way you would normally update them to a newer main.

Also, if you haven't done this already, put the old TFS repo in read only mode!
